# Using placement new in a container

Tags: c++, memory-management, placement-new, object-construction, object-destruction

I just came across some container implementation in C++. That class uses an internal buffer to manage its objects. This is a **simplified version without safety checks**:

```
template <typename E> class Container
{
public:
   Container() : buffer(new E[100]), size(0) {}
   ~Container() { delete [] buffer; }

   void Add() { buffer[size] = E(); size++; }
   void Remove() { size--; buffer[size].~E(); }

private:
   E* buffer;
   int size;
};
```

AFAIK this will construct/destruct `E` objects redundantly in `Container()` and `~Container()` if `new`/`delete` are not customized. This seems dangerous.

Is using placement `new` in `Add()` the best way to prevent dangerous redundant constructor / destructor calls (apart from binding the class to a fully featured pool)?

When using placement `new`, would `new char[sizeof(E)*100]` be the correct way for allocating the buffer?

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this code but *there is no placement-`new`* in this code.

Comment: No it isn't. I never said it would.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the question then.

Comment: @mindriot: Your are right. Error due to extraction of the example. Fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> AFAIK this will construct/destruct `E` objects redundantly

It would appear so. The `new`ed array already applies the default constructor and the `delete[]` would call destructor as well for all the elements. In effect, the `Add()` and `Remove()` methods add little other than maintain the `size` counter.

> When using placement new, would `new char[sizeof(E)*100]` be the correct way for allocating the buffer?

The best would be to opt for the [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) that handles all of the memory issues for you already.

Using a placement `new` and managing the memory yourself requires you to be aware of a number of issues (including);

- Alignment
- Allocated and used size
- Destruction
- Construction issues such as emplacement
- Possible aliasing

None of these are impossible to surmount, it has just already been done in the standard library. If you are interested in pursuing a custom allocator, the [global allocation functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) (`void* operator new (std::size_t count);`) would be the appropriate starting point for the memory allocations.

---

Without further explanation on the original purpose of the code - a `std::vector` or a `std::array` would be far better options for managing the elements in the container.

Comment: I didn't know `std::allocator` gave stronger guarantees than a simple placement-new. Could you link to a reference somewhere? (cppreference, or section from standard)

Comment: @YamMarcovic. It makes it easier because it already does all the hard work for you.

Comment: Yeah I'm just interested in the documentation of exactly what that hard work is, and whether it actually differs from placement-new. It's basically a documentation link I'm after (teach a man to fish... =] )

Comment: I see that standard containers are the best solution. But currently I need to understand the existing code. So would 'new char[sizeof(E)*100]' be the correct way of buffer allocation for placement new?

Comment: @YamMarcovic. It is already linked in the post http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator. The standard allocator (generally) would use the placement `new` as well as the global allocation and deallocation functions. It is just that it is well tested and deals with the memory issues at play.

Comment: @Silicomancer. No, it would correct to use the global allocation function `::new (sizeof(E)*100);`

Comment: @Niall Which part of that page specifies what I asked about? Could you point to a particular paragraph or statement?

Comment: @YamMarcovic. Um, I'm sure what you are after then. The construct method http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct uses the placement new in it's implementation.

Comment: @Niall Oh, I see now. `::allocate()` calls `::new()` which guarantees proper alignment, and then  `::construct()` will construct right at that aligned address using placement-new. Thanks for your patience. :)

Comment: @YamMarcovic. No problem. Looking into the implementation of something like `vector` in your standard library implementation also offers some guidance on the use of `std::allocator` as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of issues with the code.
If you call `Remove()` before calling `Add()` you will perform assignment *to* a destructed object.

Otherwise the `delete[] buffer` will call the destructor of 100 objects in the array. Which may have been called before.

Here's a valid program:

```
#include <iostream>

int counter=0;

class Example {

    public:
        Example():ID(++counter){
           std::cout<<"constructing "<<ID<<std::endl;
        }
        ~Example(){
            std::cout<<"destructing "<<ID<<std::endl;
            ID=-1;
        }
    private:


      int ID;
};

template <typename E> class Container
{
public:
   Container() : buffer(new char [100*sizeof(E)]), size(0) {}
   ~Container() {
        for(size_t i=0;i<size;++i){
            reinterpret_cast<E*>(buffer)[i].~E();
        }
        delete []  buffer; 
    }

   void Add() { new (buffer+sizeof(E)*size) E(); size++; }
   void Remove() { reinterpret_cast<E*>(buffer)[--size].~E(); }

private:
   void* buffer;
   size_t size;
};


int main() {
    Container<Example> empty;

    Container<Example> single;
    Container<Example> more;

    single.Add();

    more.Add();

    more.Remove();

    more.Add();
    more.Add();
    more.Remove();

    return 0;
}
```