# c++ allocator: operator new or placement new

Tags: c++, new-operator, allocator, placement-new

After reading this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129485/using-placement-new-in-a-container), I've known that `placement new` was too hard to use properly. Then I found `std::allocator`, so I thought `std::allocator` should have used `placement new` because it could separate allocation and do construction in two steps.

However, it seems that [How are allocator in C++ implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52255327/how-are-allocator-in-c-implemented) tells me that `std::allocator` is implemented by `operator new`, instead of `placement new`. I'm confused now. If it doesn't use `placement new`, how could it separate allocation and do construction in two steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to differ between [the `operator new` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and [`new` expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

The former (the `operator new` function) only allocates memory. The latter (`new` expression) *calls* `operator new` to allocate memory and then invokes the constructor.

---

[`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) have two functions to implement allocation and construction: [`allocate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate) and [`construct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct).

The `allocate` function uses the `operator new` function to allocate memory. The `construct` function uses placement-new to construct objects. Which seems to be the two-step process you want.

Comment: construct is no longer required to be on std::allocator, you can't rely on it being on any arbitrary allocator.